# import cv2 error caused by ROS!

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have anaconda installed. `which python` gives me the following output:

```
/home/nehal/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Now when I start python on command line, it starts the anaconda's python but `import cv2` gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
```

In the .bashrc I have :

```
export PATH="/home/nehal/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/dist-package‌​s:$PYTHONPATH"
ROS_IP=
ROS_HOSTNAME=
ROS_MASTER_URI=
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

and nothing else related to python in `.bashrc`

```
nehal@nehal-Inspiron-5559:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/nehal/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-package‌​s:/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/dist-package‌​s:/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/dist-package‌​s:/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/dist-package‌​s:/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/dist-package‌​s:/home/userx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/dist-package‌​s:/home/userx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/dist-package‌​s:/home/userx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/dist-package‌​s
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290660/import-cv2--error-caused-by-ros!/) by [nrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33066/nrb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2018-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're mixing Anaconda (which is apparently Python 3) with python modules that are compiled for cPython 2.7. These are incompatible and won't work together.

You may want to try either:

- Don't use Anaconda when you use ROS (use one or the other, but not both)
- Recompile ROS and the OpenCV python library to use Anaconda (I have no idea how to do this, but you can probably find instructions online)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33066/nrb/) on 2018-05-08**:
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i met the same problem, here is how i "solved" it, ugly but worked

write "import cv2" into

```
import sys
sys.path.remove('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages') # in order to import cv2 under python3
import cv2
sys.path.append('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages') # append back in order to import rospy
```

---

Originally posted by [lochlomond](https://answers.ros.org/users/44598/lochlomond/) with karma: 61 on 2019-08-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amiryanj](https://answers.ros.org/users/50483/amiryanj/) on 2019-12-24**:
Wow! It's working. Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [pry](https://answers.ros.org/users/52744/pry/) on 2020-03-21**:
Thanks a lot, it works

**Comment by [myth1665](https://answers.ros.org/users/54840/myth1665/) on 2020-05-11**:
solved ,thanks

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2020-07-31**:
this should be an accepted answer though